# comparing values in cells from a sheet to find identical values i a different column in a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

If the values in columns 1 and 2 are the same in columns A and B the copy corresponding value of column 3 and paste in column C .removing duplicates then pasting the values.

```
Sub copyCurrentStatus()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1

            'If Worksheets("Sending List").Range("C:C").Value = Worksheets("P13 D-Chain Status").Range("A:A").Value Then
             If Worksheets("Sending List").Cells(i, 1).Value = Worksheets("P13 D-Chain Status").Range("i,1").Value Then

               'Copy Sales Organization
                Rows(i).Copy
                Worksheets("Sending List").Range("D:D").PasteSpecial

            End If
        Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to qualify the worksheet that `Rows(i)` is on. Where exactly should it be pasted (why do you have `D:D`?) Then use `.Cells` instead of `.Range` in `Range("i,1")` (and lose the quotes).

Comment: i want to paste it on column D in a different sheet. can you help me with you code, they way you understood the problem posed ?? thanks